Diffusion equation with complex coefficient
This is the solution for diffusion equation(3 dimensional):

Now, I want to solve $u_t=\frac{\epsilon+i}{2}\Delta u$ (in $R^3$), $u(X,0)=\phi(X)$; where $\epsilon>0$ and $i$ is complex number.
Use the above result, we got $u(X,t)={1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi t}}^3{\sqrt {\epsilon+i}}^3}\iiint exp[-{|X-X'|^2 \over 2(\epsilon+i)t}]\phi(X')dX'$.
But there is a problem.
${\sqrt {\epsilon+i}}$ represents two different value, $a+ib$ and $-a-ib$, where $a$, $b$ are both positive. Which one is reasonable?

If $u$ is a solution to $u_t = k\Delta u$, then so is $-u$ -- but only one of these will satisfy the initial condition $u(\mathbf{x},0) = \phi(\mathbf{x})$, right?
